# how to update metatags using metatag_manager?

Tags: meta-tags

I have drupal 10 installation, I am trying to update robots metatag for old articles/pages, I am writing an update_hook .

I found this really clean way to get the metatags parameters :

```
$metatag_manager = \Drupal::service('metatag.manager');
```

First, get the tags from the entity (usually from a node):

```
$tags = $metatag_manager->tagsFromEntityWithDefaults($node);
```

and then generate the meta tag values:

```
$metatags = $metatag_manager->generateTokenValues($tags, $node);
```

However, is there a way to update the metatags using the metatag_manager ?
I couldnt manage to update the metatags and save the node after.

KR,
Asmaa